Skew Symmetric Matrix vs. Cross Product
This might be more of a programming question in truth (at least, I suspect the answer is related to computer programming), but I figured I'd ask here. Why would someone choose to represent a cross product between vectors as the skew symmetric matrix of the first vector times the second vector? What is the advantage of this?
Again, gut tells me that it's related to the idea that just writing a function that maps vector 1 into this matrix and performs the operation is the most straightforward way to code.

The great mathematician Vladimir Arnold was definitely  ot interested in programming when he wrote his marvellous book on Classical Mechanics. See the chapter on rotation of rigid bodies in there.
